# Is it possible to trigger a click event inside an iframe loaded with 3rd party content from another domain?

Tags: javascript, iframe, click, mouseevent

I have accomplished reach the desired element inside of the iframe but I can't fire click events. I have used `click()` and `initMouseEvent("click", true, true)` without success.

So is it possible to trigger a click event inside an iframe loaded with 3rd party content from another domain?

Comment: i think its not possible.  if it possible we can do lot of things. for example .. we can auto trigger the facbook like button and many more...

Comment: Wouldn't hackers love to be able to do that. :-(

Comment: You said it. Well, seen in that way...

Answer (score 2):

What I have learned the last hours:

In first place: It should be no possible due violates the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) especially in these days where exists a lot of code being injected via iframes in the most of pages: Ads and social bookmarks widgets and so on...

In second place: It is very probable that this kind of code commits some legal violations to the 3rd party entity.

So the answer to the question *seems* be No.